# Array after a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function

Hello im new in react sometimes i find there are array after a function, I tried to find the use of it, can explain the use of it or provide a link for the documentation for will be helpful. Thank you

This is the example of the code

```
export const PostsList = () => {  
    const {
      data: posts = [],
      isLoading,
      isSuccess,
      isError,
      error
    } = useGetPostsQuery()
    
    const sortedPosts = useMemo(() => {
    const sortedPosts = posts.slice()
    sortedPosts.sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))

    return sortedPosts
    
  }, [posts])}
```

I dont know the use of [posts] at the end of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formatting your code better will make it clearer what the array is actually used for:

```
    const sortedPosts = useMemo(() => {
        const sortedPosts = posts.slice()
        sortedPosts.sort((a, b) => b.date.localeCompare(a.date))
        return sortedPosts
    }, [posts])
}
```

The array is used as a parameter to `useMemo`, a React hook.

Many React hooks (functions that start with `use`) make use of such an array. These are called "dependency arrays." Generally, what the array means is:

- Whenever one of the items in the array changes render-to-render, re-calculate the value inside, and use the new value
- If all of the items in the array stay the same during a new render, return the item calculated during the last render

In this case, with `useMemo`, it means that the `sortedPosts` will only be re-calculated when the `posts` changes. If there's a re-render when `posts` doesn't change, the value returned by the *previous render*'s `useMemo` will be used for `sortedPosts` instead.

Re-using the old value instead of calculating and using the value anew on each render improves performance, because it means that when the value is passed down to *other* components, they won't have to re-render if the value is the same (`===` to the value from the past render).

Look at [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) for hooks for details on what the array does for each different hook.

Comment: Very good and clear explanation sir! Thank you for the explanation and suggestion!